# Programmatically open a new tab in ie7

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer-7, tabs

I am developing web applications with c#, Aspnet 3.5, and Ajax 2.0.

Question - I run Application_1 in ie7. I would like to programmatically start running Application_2 from Application_1 in a new tab, no matter what the client settings are.

Until now I have been opening Application_2 in  a new window from Application_1 using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "window.open('theurl',' width=800, height=500'); ", true);
```

I would like to do something similar to open a new tab.

Comment: However...
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.youtube.com")
will use an existing Internet browser and open in new tab if supported. on the other hand:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore","http://www.youtube.com")
this will open a new instance of iexplore

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no way to control whether the window opens in a new tab or new window. This is a user setting that can't be overridden in code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is Microsoft's justification if you're interested.

*"Regarding script, there is no "target='_tab'" feature or any direct access to tabs from script beyond what is available with multiple windows today. We are working on balancing the default behavior for whether a window opened from script opens as in a new frame or a tab."*

- [IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/05/26/422103.aspx)

You could inform your user that by holding ctrl+shift and clicking a link will open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul already noted, this cannot be done via any script or code.

I think it's best to let your users decide (via their individual browser settings) how they want to open the new page - in a new window or in a new tab in the same window.